# Send to a negative MPI rank destination

Tags: c, mpi

I was wondering what happens whenever i specify a negative rank as a destination while sending or a negative rank as a source when receiving. This can happen when using `MPI_Cart`. In most definitions it only states "Ranks must be between zero and the size of the communicator minus one" [Mpich documentation](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.3/www3/MPI_Send.html). Thus I wonder whether I need to safeguard against this or whether this is bad style to not block this explicitly from happening. Is writing code like this safe and good practice?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int size, rank;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    fprintf(stdout, "Size: %i Rank: %i\n", size, rank);

    int a = 10;

    if (rank == 0){
        a++;
        MPI_Send(
                &a,
                1,
                MPI_INT,
                -2,
                0,
                MPI_COMM_WORLD
        );
    }

    if (rank == 1){
        MPI_Recv(
                &a,
                1,
                MPI_INT,
                -2,
                0,
                MPI_COMM_WORLD,
                MPI_STATUS_IGNORE
        );
    }

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    fprintf(stdout, "Size: %i Rank: %i a: %i\n", size, rank, a);

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `MPI_PROC_NULL` is usually defined as `-1` or `-2`, and sending to the null proc always succeeds. Ditto receiving: your receive buffer will remain unchanged. Sending to other negative values will probably give an error about "invalid rank". However, it's dangerous to rely on the explicit values because it can be installation dependent.

You should test for `MPI_PROC_NULL` and skip those operations. In fact, I suspect that your Cartesian routines are defined as giving you that value, rather than explicitly `-1`. Also, Cartesian routines may state "thou shalt not use coordinates outside the grid" and doing do is probably undefined behavior.

Comment: The above example runs without throwing any error. The Cartesian routine returns an integer with the value -2 on my and a couple of other systems/compilers/libraries I have tried. How could I go about testing whether it is safe or not? Or is it better just to safeguard with an additional if clause? Thank you

Comment: Look up the definition of your cartesian routine. It may say that the result can be `MPI_PROC_NULL` so then you test on that. It can also say "you should not use coordinates outside the grid" and it's undefined behavior when you do.

Comment: Oh, and print out the value of `MPI_PROC_NULL`?

Comment: Yes, the value of `MPI_PROC_NULL` is equal to the aforementioned -2

Comment: Do you have OpenMPI? I think it's -1 on mpich-derived implementations.

Comment: I am locally running OpenMPI, but later have to switch to the Intel library, as the HPC-center I am running the code on is Intel based.